# How to keep my desktop icons organized on laptop when I connect and disconnect an external screen?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, desktop-icons

I'm using Windows 10 1803 and having a laptop with 1080p resolution with a recommended zoom of 150% (since 100% looks too small on a 13.3" screen).
When I'm at work I have 2 monitors which are connected to it and my desktop icons are organized in a certain way.

When I disconnect my monitors and use the laptop's monitor the icons doesn't keep organized like I had them before connecting the monitors.

Is it possible to have 2 sets of desktop icons organization?

Thanks!

Comment: DesktopOK works for me.

Comment: Thanks.So I assume there isn't anything built in the windows itself, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so apparently windows 10 already take care of that and remember the positions of my icons.

Currently running Windows 10 Version 1803.